# Why redux state might be undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In redux I want to make a selector getRequestStatus:

```
export const getRequestStatus = (state) => state.books.request
```

For unknown reason, it doesn't work in component when I use `mapStateToProps` and says `state.books` is undefined.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
  getBook: (bookId) => getBook(state,bookId),
  getRequestStatus: (state)=>getRequestStatus(state),//doesn't work, undefined state.books
})
```

Suprisingly it works fine when write in component:

```
   const request = useSelector((state)=>getRequestStatus(state))//works
```

When I don't use `useSelector` I try to call this from props:

```
 const request = getRequestStatus()//doesn't work, cant access to undefined state.books
//normally it should because state is passed in mapStateToProps right?
```

I suppose that this is because of no state argument. What Do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRequestStatus: (state)=>getRequestStatus(state)` should just be `getRequestStatus: ()=>getRequestStatus(state)`

Comment: Thanks. It works :)